# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

customers.html is not rendering.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mSnF.png)

My Controller Class
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3nRV.png)

My Model Class
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffr8V.png)

Error Logs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2YE5.png)

Can someone please suggest me what is needed to be done here?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, code etc. Copy the original text to your question and format it properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.